Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined' - sanity, remix and typescript
I am struggling with TypeScript in my Sanity/Remix application when I try to access references. I have a RoleType, where you can create a role and give the role a title and reference it to a Person. The PersonType has a name field that is required.
This is what the types looks like:
RoleGroup Sanity type:
export default {
 name: "roleGroup",
 title: "Rollegruppe",
 type: "object",
 fields: [
  defineField({
    name: "persons",
    title: "Personer",
    type: "array",
    of: [
      {
       type: "object",
       fields: [
        {
          name: "person",
          title: "Person",
          type: "reference",
          to: [{ type: "person" }],
          options: {
            filter: ({ document }) => {
              return {
                filter: "language == $lang",
                params: { lang: document.language },
              };
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
   ],
  }),
 ],
};

PersonType in Sanity
export const personType = defineType({
 name: "person",
 title: "Person",
 type: "document",
 icon: UserIcon,
 preview: {
  select: {
   title: "name",
   media: "image",
  },
},
fields: [
  defineField({
  name: "name",
  title: "Navn",
  type: "string",
  validation: (rule) =>
    rule.required().min(1).error(`Name is required`),
  }),
 ],
});

I use 'npx sanity schema extract && npx sanity typegen generate' to generate the schemas in sanity.types.ts with types so I can use them in the remix application.
This is the RoleGroup type in sanity.types.ts:
export type RoleGroup = {
 _type: "roleGroup";
 name?: string;
 persons?: Array<{
   person?: {
    _ref: string;
    _type: "reference";
    _weak?: boolean;
    [internalGroqTypeReferenceTo]?: "person";
 };
  occupation?: string;
  _key: string;
 }>;
 };

And this is the person type in sanity.types.ts:
export type Person = {
  _id: string;
  _type: "person";
  _createdAt: string;
  _updatedAt: string;
  _rev: string;
  name?: string;
   language?: string;
  image?: {
    asset?: {
     _ref: string;
     _type: "reference";
     _weak?: boolean;
   [internalGroqTypeReferenceTo]?: "sanity.imageAsset";
  };
   hotspot?: SanityImageHotspot;
   crop?: SanityImageCrop;
   alt?: string;
   credit?: string;
   _type: "customImage";
   };
  text?: string;
  };

This is the relevant code of the groq query:
 roleGroups[]{
  _type,
  name, 
  persons[]{
  _type,
  occupation, 
  person->{name, image, text}
  }
},

In my Remix application, I am iterating through the roleGroups, and I want to use the RoleGroup type like this:
{roleGroups?.map((group: RoleGroup, i: number) => (
      <RolesBlock key={i} roleGroup={group} />
    ))}

I get this typescript error in vscode on group: RoleGroup:
Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'

However, in the RoleBlock component - when I try to access the properties (like image, name etc) it works like it should. Everything else works as it should. The only issue is that Typescript complains on the property in the reference.
Any idea how this can be solved?

I believe the issue is when calling the type generator. Try: npx sanity schema extract --enforce-required-fields
it should return the types as:
exampleprop:  string | null
instead of just
exampleprop?: string <<< which means: string | undefined.

I did try that but it does not work.
The reference type still looks like this
person: {
name: string | null;
}
while the PersonType looks like this
export type Person {
name?: string;
}
The defineType now looks like this:
defineField({
name: "name",
title: "Navn",
type: "string",
validation: (Rule) => Rule.required().error("Required"),
}),
I also tried without validation, and using Rule.required().min(1) without luck.
